# How can you put multicolor backgrounds in a table entry?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, backgrounds

I'm wondering if these is a simple way shade an entry in a table with multiple background colors. Image attached shows between 0-3 colors per table item entry.

[image]

Comment: You can use a `tikz` `matrix` and fill them at will.

Comment: Just posting an image and crossing your fingers sometimes work if a member of the procrastination team is particularly interested and takes the hook. But a more reliable strategy is to post a minimum working example with the code you've got, which does the parts you can and allows you to ask a specific question about a particular obstacle you are facing. This also makes your question more generally useful to other users, less likely to be misunderstood and, therefore, both easier and less hazardous to answer.

Comment: @cfr Is there such a thing as a procrastination team around here? ;)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina There is `tikz` mafia! :-)   I came back to answer only to find that you already did. :)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Of course! The team is even [featured on meta](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/430/text-building-blocks) . No idea who is in it, though ;).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is straightforward using TikZ:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,backgrounds}

\definecolor{mybrown}{RGB}{33,34,28}
\definecolor{myyellow}{RGB}{242,226,149}
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{176,232,145}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{61,139,189}
\definecolor{myorange}{RGB}{245,156,74}
\definecolor{mypurple}{RGB}{230,111,148}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{215,80,50}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[
  matrix of nodes,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
  nodes={
    draw,
    text width=5em,
    align=center,
    minimum height=3ex
  }
] (mat)
{
  Title1 & Title2 \\
  Foo1 & Bar1 \\
  Foo2 & Bar2 \\
  Foo3 & |[fill=myblue]|Bar3 \\
  Foo4 & Bar4 \\
};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
%two color fill
\fill[fill=myblue!80]
  (mat-2-2.north west) rectangle
  ( $ (mat-2-2.south west)!0.5!(mat-2-2.south east) $ );
\fill[fill=mypurple!80]
  ( $ (mat-2-2.north west)!0.5!(mat-2-2.north east) $ ) rectangle
  (mat-2-2.south east);

%three color fill
\fill[fill=myred!80]
  (mat-3-2.north west) rectangle
  ( $ (mat-3-2.south west)!0.3333!(mat-3-2.south east) $ );
\fill[fill=mygreen!80]
  ( $ (mat-3-2.north west)!0.3333!(mat-3-2.north east) $ ) rectangle
  ( $ (mat-3-2.south west)!0.6666!(mat-3-2.south east) $ );
\fill[fill=myblue!80]
  ( $ (mat-3-2.north west)!0.6666!(mat-3-2.north east) $ ) rectangle
  (mat-3-2.south east);

%four color fill
\fill[fill=myorange!80]
  (mat-5-2.north west) rectangle
  ( $ (mat-5-2.south west)!0.25!(mat-5-2.south east) $ );
\fill[fill=mygreen!80]
  ( $ (mat-5-2.north west)!0.25!(mat-5-2.north east) $ ) rectangle
  ( $ (mat-5-2.south west)!0.50!(mat-5-2.south east) $ );
\fill[fill=myyellow]
  ( $ (mat-5-2.north west)!0.50!(mat-5-2.north east) $ ) rectangle
  ( $ (mat-5-2.south west)!0.75!(mat-5-2.south east) $ );
\fill[fill=myblue!80]
  ( $ (mat-5-2.north west)!0.75!(mat-5-2.north east) $ ) rectangle
  (mat-5-2.south east);
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. I wouldn't exactly call this stuff "easy", though. Maybe "straightforward"?

Comment: @Mico Agreed. Change made.

Answer (score 0):

A solution non generalized  with `array`, `xcolor`. The  problem that i have  encountered is centering "Bar1" any one has a best way of centering is invited to correct it.

**Code**

```
\documentclass[margin=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\newlength{\len}
\settowidth{\len}{Bar1}
\def\mylen{\dimexpr -0.2\len -2\tabcolsep}

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\cellcolor{#1!25}}m{\dimexpr 1cm-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{Y}[1]{>{\centering\cellcolor{#1!25}}m{\dimexpr 2cm-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{Z}[1]{>{\centering\cellcolor{#1!25}}m{\dimexpr 4cm-2\tabcolsep}}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\cellcolor{#1!25}}m{\dimexpr 2cm-2\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.8pt}

\begin{tabular}{|c|cccc|}
\hline
Title1 & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Title2}\\
\hline
Foo1   & \multicolumn{2}{|Y{green}}{}& \multicolumn{2}{L{blue}|}{\hspace*{\mylen}Bar1}\\
\hline
Foo2   & \multicolumn{1}{|C{red}}{}& \multicolumn{2}{Y{green}}{Bar2}&\multicolumn{1}{C{blue}|}{}\\
\hline
Foo3   & \multicolumn{4}{|Z{blue}|}{Bar3}\\
\hline
Foo4   & \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Bar4}\\
\hline

\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image]