# Multi-colored cell background

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, color, cellcolor

I have been successfully using `xcolor` and its `\cellcolor` command for a while, and produced beautiful results with it. However, I would like to create some more advanced background effects: color the cell with two colors:

[image: Example of attempted solutions]

The example above is produced using https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/263403/17312, but this approach falls apart for a number of reasons:

1. Tikz's matrix command is not nearly as powerful as ordinary tabulars with the `array` package and others. I have some numeric data that I am happily aligning on the decimal point using `dcolumn` - I have no idea how I would do this is in a tikz matrix.
2. I would like to emulate booktabs behaviour, but I just can't get it working. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21178/17312 suggests a workaround, but it doesn't work.
3. The coloring falls apart if the width of the columns is not predefined:
   [image: Example 2]

   and it all falls apart.
4. I have had a look through other questions; https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/346212/17312 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/81998/17312 manage to create one-colored bars dynamically; https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148797/17312 combines `tabularx` and `tikz` in a promising approach, but I did not manage to adapt this to my purpose; [Aligning tikz nodes to tabular cells?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/115950/17312) draws lines and manages to stick to a tabular environment - maybe a good starting point?

So ideally I would like to stick to a `tabular` environment, and be able to specify the cells' background content freely (for the point of this question I would be happy with a solution that gives me the diagonally separated effect as in the top left corner of the two examples), with a command such as `\twocolor{blue}{purple}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more flexible background definition can be done by collecting from [my answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/343674/81905) to [TikZ: Rectangle with diagonal fill (two colors)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343354/tikz-rectangle-with-diagonal-fill-two-colors) and [Gonzalo's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67096/81905) to [Set table background hatched and shaded using tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/67092/set-table-background-hatched-and-shaded-using-tikz). There are some spacing issues, mostly (I think) because I'm not quite aware of the padding macros inside the `tabular` cells, specially with `booktabs` rules (`toprule`, `\midrule`,...), so it works better with `\hline` right now, but I'm sure it can be easily improved.

The column specifier is not overruled, but it needs to be specified explicitly. In the below MWE I use `dcolumn` but I recommend the use of `siunitx` instead, as done by Salim Bou.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark, calc}
% Makes a style for double color filling
\tikzset{
    double color fill/.code 2 args={
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[%
            tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom%
        ]{diagonalfill}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)
        }
        \tikzset{shade, left color=#1, right color=#2, shading=diagonalfill}
    }
}
% Code adapted from Gonzalo: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/67096/81905
\newcommand\BGcell[4][0pt]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]%
    \path[#4] ( $ (pic cs:#2) + (-.5\tabcolsep,1.9ex) $ ) rectangle ( $ (pic cs:#3) + (\tabcolsep,-#1*\baselineskip-.8ex) $ );
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}%
\newcounter{BGnum}
\setcounter{BGnum}{1}
\newcommand\cellBG[3]{
    \multicolumn{1}{
        !{\BGcell{startBG\arabic{BGnum}}{endBG\arabic{BGnum}}{%
                #1}
            \tikzmark{startBG\arabic{BGnum}}}
            #2
        !{\tikzmark{endBG\arabic{BGnum}}}}
        {#3} 
      \addtocounter{BGnum}{1}
}
% end of code from Gonzalo

\usepackage{dcolumn, array, booktabs}
\newcolumntype{.}{D{.}{.}{-1}}
\newcommand*{\tabhead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
  \tikzset{%
    diagonal fill/.style 2 args={%
        double color fill={#1}{#2},
        shading angle=45,
        opacity=0.8},
    other filling/.style={%
        shade,
        shading=myshade,
        shading angle=0,
        opacity=0.5}
   }
  % Other crazy filling options using shading
  \pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshade}{100bp}{%
      color(0bp)=(blue);
      color(25bp)=(blue);
      color(37.5bp)=(blue);
      color(37.5bp)=(brown);
      color(50bp)=(brown);
      color(50bp)=(green);
      color(62.5bp)=(green);
      color(62.5bp)=(purple);
      color(75bp)=(red);
      color(100bp)=(red)}

  \begin{tabular}{c.}
    \toprule
    \cellBG{double color fill={red}{blue}, shading angle=-45, opacity=0.5}{c}{Header 1} & \tabhead{Header 2}\\
    \midrule
    \cellBG{diagonal fill={yellow}{green}}{c}{Text} & \cellBG{other filling}{.}{1.2333}\\
    \cellBG{other filling}{c}{Text} & 154.622\\
    Text & 1.244\\
    Text & 11.3\\
    Text & 121.2\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

This method relies on Ti*k*Z shadings, they're not so complicated to define and are very powerful. One thing to take into account when declaring a shading is that if you define it to be of `100bp` it will automatically scale, and the visible part of the shading will be between `25bp` and `75bp`, that's why my Multi Color shading has blue from `0bp` to `25bp`, because that part is actually hidden. The key `shading angle` can be used to set the diagonal slant, other types of shading can be defined as well (check the manual for more info).

[image]

Comment: Very nice. This comes closest to what I want to achieve. Why does the content of each cell needs to be wrapped in another `\multicolumn`?

Comment: Because if you look closely, inside the column specifier, in the `\multicolumn` there's a `!{...}` declaration which computes the mark from `tikzmark`. You could maybe create `\newcolumntype`s to compute the marks for every cell but only background selectively...

Answer (score 4):

Based on @leoLiu [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/17748/54817) to create cell with diagonal line. 
In the example I use `suinitx` rather then `dcolumn` to align numbers on decimal point.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}


\newcommand\diagfil[4]{%
  \multicolumn{1}{p{#1}}{\hskip-\tabcolsep
  $\vcenter{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=0,anchor=south west,inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt]
  \path[use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (#1+2\tabcolsep,\baselineskip);
  \node[minimum width={#1+2\tabcolsep},minimum height=\baselineskip+\extrarowheight+\belowrulesep+\aboverulesep,fill=#2] (box)at(0,-\aboverulesep) {};
  \fill [#3] (box.south west)--(box.north east)|- cycle;
  \node[anchor=center] at (box.center) {#4};
  \end{tikzpicture}}$\hskip-\tabcolsep}}

\begin{document}

\centering

\begin{tabular}{SSSSS}
\toprule
\diagfil{2cm}{blue}{purple}{Text} &&&&2.0\\
\midrule
  &  &  &  &3.03\\ 
15&12&18&50&4.5\\
15&12&18&50&4.54\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting approach! However this overwrites the column definition for the cell - (e.g.) I would like to be able to get the decimal point alignment also in the cell with the background.

Answer (score 1):

With `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`, it's easy to fill a cell or a block (which is a rectangle of merged cells) with a shade of PGF/Tikz.

An instruction `\Block[tikz=shade]{n-p}{contents}` will fill the block (of n rows and p columns) with the shade *shade* (and put the *contents* in the center of the block).

**The Tikz shades of this answer are those of Zanotelli's answer.**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}



\begin{document}

% Makes a style for double color filling
\makeatletter
\tikzset{
    double color fill/.code 2 args={
        \pgfdeclareverticalshading[%
            tikz@axis@top,tikz@axis@middle,tikz@axis@bottom%
        ]{diagonalfill}{100bp}{%
            color(0bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@bottom);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@middle);
            color(50bp)=(tikz@axis@top);
            color(100bp)=(tikz@axis@top)
        }
        \tikzset{shade, left color=#1, right color=#2, shading=diagonalfill}
    }
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
  diagonal fill/.style 2 args={%
      double color fill={#1}{#2},
      shading angle=45,
      opacity=0.8},
  other filling/.style={%
      shade,
      shading=myshade, % myshade is defined below
      shading angle=0,
      opacity=0.5}
 }

% Other crazy filling options using shading
\pgfdeclarehorizontalshading{myshade}{100bp}{%
    color(0bp)=(blue);
    color(25bp)=(blue);
    color(37.5bp)=(blue);
    color(37.5bp)=(brown);
    color(50bp)=(brown);
    color(50bp)=(green);
    color(62.5bp)=(green);
    color(62.5bp)=(purple);
    color(75bp)=(red);
    color(100bp)=(red)}

\begin{NiceTabular}{cS}
  \toprule
  \Block[tikz={double color fill={red}{blue}, shading angle=-45, opacity=0.5}]{}{Header 1} & {Header 2} \\
  \midrule
  \Block[tikz={diagonal fill={yellow}{green}}]{2-1}{Text} & \Block[tikz=other filling]{}{1.2333} \\
  & 154.622\\
  \Block[tikz = other filling]{1-1}{Text} & 1.244 \\
  Text & 11.3\\
  Text & 121.2\\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes).

[image: Output of the above code]

Comment: That is certainly a more convinient solution. Does NiceTabular support dcolumn definitions?

Comment: @Karalga: `{NiceTabular}` does not support `d` column but supports the `S` columns of `siunitx`.